# How to convert R dataframe into a list of lists?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame with 3 columns ID,  category, item_id. I want to group by ID, category, and item_id in vector

```
df <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),
              category=c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A"),
              item_id=c("1a", "2a", "1b","2b", "2b", "2a" ))
  > df
      ID category item_id
   1:  1        A      1a
   2:  1        A      2a
   3:  1        B      1b
   4:  2        B      2b
   5:  2        B      2b
   6:  2        A      2a
```

I want to convert above dataframe into list of list with item_id as vector .I want the above table in the below list format.

```
df2 <- list("1"=list("A"=c("1a", "2a"), "B"=c("2b")),
            "2"=list("A"=c("2a"), "B"=c("2b" ,"2b")))
>     df2
   $`1`
   $`1`$A
  [1] "1a" "2a"

   $`1`$B
  [1] "2b"

   $`2`
  $`2`$A
  [1] "2a"

  $`2`$B
  [1] "2b" "2b"
```

I want to apply this operation on 1 Million rows please suggest an efficient solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want a nested list we can use nested `split` :

```
lapply(split(df[, -1], df$ID), function(x) split(x$item_id, x$category))

#$`1`
#$`1`$A
#[1] "1a" "2a"

#$`1`$B
#[1] "1b"


#$`2`
#$`2`$A
#[1] "2a"

#$`2`$B
#[1] "2b" "2b"
```

Comment: Hey Ronak
this works on small data, is there any faster solution to apply on 1M rows.

Comment: I can't think of any alternate faster method now.

Comment: I tried with reshape2:melt it is super fast 
`recomendation_data_copy <- setDT(recommendation_data)`
`recomendation_data_copy <- reshape2::melt(recomendation_data_copy, measure.vars = c("item_id",paste0("Alt", 1:(p-1))), variable.name = "variable_names" , value.name = "value")`
 `recomendation_data_copy$variable_names <- NULL`

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to define your custom function `nest`, which works in a recursive manner to create nested list

```
nest <- function(x) {
  if (length(x)==2) return(split(x[,-1],x[,1]))
  lapply(split(x[-1],x[1]), nest)
}
```

such that

```
> nest(df)
$`1`
$`1`$A
[1] 1a 2a
Levels: 1a 1b 2a 2b

$`1`$B
[1] 1b
Levels: 1a 1b 2a 2b


$`2`
$`2`$A
[1] 2a
Levels: 1a 1b 2a 2b

$`2`$B
[1] 2b 2b
Levels: 1a 1b 2a 2b
```